# Debug reactjs project by executing 'make run' in visual studio code

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I have project structure as shown below. Through command line we use `make run` to start the execution but need to debug by using breakpoints in it. So how to setup in vsc.

[image]

Below is my launch.json file

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "attach",
        "name": "Attach",
        "port": 9229
    },
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/make",
            "args": [
                "run"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This doesn't work but how to setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go here first:
[image]

In the drop down above select Add configuration and select Node. THen add this in the launch.json file which opens up for you:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible Node.js debug attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Project Name Here",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/src\\server\\changeToYourAppFile.js",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "restart": true,
            "protocol": "inspector"
        }
    ]
}
```

The following is my app file:

```
server = app.listen(port, err => {
    if (err) { return console.error(err); }
    console.info('==> ✅  Express server is listening');
    console.info(`==>   Go to http://localhost:${port} [${env}]`);
});

server.timeout = 3600000;
```

Comment: make sure that the port number specified in your project is not already in use. If you are using webpack-dev-server make sure you stop that. If you are using PM2 then kill the pm2 instance and do this.

Comment: I don't have a `js` file to be invoked like you have mentioned in `configurations.program`. I have a make file so I need to run `make run`

Comment: Yeah. you do that and then put the server start code o'er there. Give this file's path in the launch.json then

Comment: Its not as simple as you have mentioned the server start code. Its configured differently. So that's the reason I was asking how to execute `make run` command from VSC